# RavenDB or SQL Server 2008 Filestream

Tags: sql-server-2008, ravendb

A project I am working on at the minute involves taking a massive set of results stored in a file and doing calculations based on those results.  I have been looking at using either RavenDB or using the SQL2008 with the Filestream as the storage for the results.  I am not sure which technology would be best suited to my problem.
Has anyone any views on which of these approaches is best for massive storage and possible searching of results?

Comment: I think they could both work, but you need to share quite a bit more information. That and why would you just sue a SQL 2008 filestream to store the results? Might as well just use a file at that point and save yourself $5k a processor.

Comment: Also, can you define "massive set of results" - roughly what order are we talking about?

Comment: The results will have roughly 100,000 inserts.  I have done a quick test with 100000 inserts with RavenDb and was getting a time out error, so I am going to look into the various configurations and see what the performance is like.  Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to insert a lot of data to Raven and was also disappointed in the first place, because I did it all form one thread. It turned out that inserting to SQL Server was faster (without doing much configuration on both servers).

Then I realized that I probably misused Raven, which is - as far as I understand it - designed to handle massive parallelism. So I played a bit with TPL opening a lot of threads / processes doing inserts in parallel. Raven handled this very well - but keep the "eventual consistency" in mind - not all the results showed up in the database immediatly but with a short delay.

I think a direct comparrison is hard unless you adjust your architecture to fit the choosen storage technology.